# Getting Wi-fi network response time on android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, packet

I want to get an access point response time.
I notice  that last API has a `public long timestamp` in class `ScanResult`.
Unfortunately, I want something that can run over 2.3+.

It's possible to get the "Probe Response" packet of an access point? And so getting the complete packet information, like time, etc.?

I've searched over SO and googled a lot, but I've not found a simple way to send a custom packet over network, or how to receive it.

I would appreciate any hints!

Thank you